# Subscript of Walktrap igraph

Tags: r, igraph

Lately I have been learning to use `cluster_walktrap` function in `igraph` packages to determine community structure in some sample networks. However, I stumped into the following problem: .

```
 Error in names[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

This happens when I set an object `Community = cluster_walktrap(network,steps = 5, merges = TRUE)`. 
Can you help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: What does the `network` variable contain?

Comment: I set set network as a graph getting from an csv edgelist file.

Comment: Please create [a complete minimal example](http://sscce.org/) and post it on https://igraph.discourse.group/

Comment: I am voting to close this question because there is not enough information to reproduce the problem. The following works fine: `g<-make_graph("zachary"); cluster_walktrap(g, steps=5, merges=T)`.

Comment: Once again, please show a complete minimal example so we can determine if this is a bug in igraph or a mistake in how you are using it.